# Mesh Networking with a Multiple Raspberry PIs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adhoc, mesh-network

I am interested in figuring out how to set up a network between X amounts of devices in which they could come and go from the network with nodes. Just as the python library https://github.com/pirate/mesh-networking outlines.

My question is how do I go about configuring the adapters to work on a node like a system where they would not need to connect or disconnect from a network and be able to monitor who is connected to the network all while having safe encryption between the nodes.

Preferably I would like to configure and deploy everything from within a python script.

Is this possible? and if so where can I find more information regarding on how to configure to adapters to do this.

Thanks